# Ending of Welcher in "Welche berühmten Stars hast du schon mal getroffen?"

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective-ending

When I was reading the sentence

> Welche berühmten Stars hast du schon mal getroffen?

I was left puzzled as the last time I recall using definite articles and adjectives, I thought an **-en** ending would be applied, hence I believed:

> Welchen berühmten Stars hast du schon mal getroffen?

would be correct.

Why is this not true here?

Comment: You do not say why you thought it should be *welchen*. https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/welcher#Interrogativpronomen,_m,_f

Answer (score 6):

In the sentence

> Welch**e** berühmten **Stars** hast du schon mal getroffen?

the word *Stars* is plural. The other sentence would be correct if *Star* was singular:

> Welch**en** berühmten **Star** hast du schon mal getroffen?

Note: one Star, not many Stars.

Comment: Interesting- and confusingly also "*Welche berühmten Stare hast du schon mal getroffen?*" and "*Welchen berühmten Staren hast du schon mal getroffen?*" are viable sentences, but then you speak about starlings, a species of birds.

Comment: "Welche berühmten Stars" is not a sentence.

Comment: The *object* is plural. To say that the sentence is plural is at least misleading if not outright wrong because the verb is singular.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct as stated.

The second one would be correct if you would change it to

> Welchen der berühmten Stars hast du schon mal getroffen?

although then the semantics would change. It depends on whether you want to know about all the famous celebrities you ever met or rather which one of the many you ever met.

Comment: Die Verwendung des Demonstrativpronomens _der_ würde betonen, dass nur die _berühmten_, nicht aber die _unberühmten_ Stars gemeint wären. Rhetorische Frage: Gibt es unberühmte Stars? Grammatisch mögen Sie also Recht haben, aber inhaltlich?

Comment: war vom op so formuliert... also übernehme ich damit er seine frage noch wieder erkennt :-) ansonsten sieh's als pleonasmus...

Answer (score 1):

*Welcher/welche/welches*, being a pronoun, has the -e ending in both nominative plural and accusative plural. You can easily look up a declension table on the Web.

As far as the following adjectives are concerned, it behaves like an article (it is an *Artikelwort*). This means the following adjective(s) use weak declension. In weak declension, the plural always ends with -en, in all genders and cases.

That's why it's correct to say:

> Welche berühmt**en** Stars hast du schon mal getroffen?

but without the *welche* you say:

> Hast du berühmt**e** Stars getroffen?